# PhoneGap: Is there a base time not the current set time

Tags: cordova, time, phonegap-plugins

I need to grab a time which cannot be changed by the user.

Is there something like a phone time, which works with an offset to the time the user sets?

I am programming a timetracker, so I do not want the user to be able to 'hack' the time.
Is that possible?

For Android (if you direkt me to the right direction) I can write a plugin myself. But for iOS I would need help, if there is nothing out of the box.

Help is highly appreciated

[I am not looking for javascript ::new Date()::]

Comment: I think you can detect if the user changes the time. But maybe you should check an online clock like `http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now`

Comment: @jcesarmobile: that would work, but I need it basically for the offline availablity. So the user stamps offline and sends it later.